# Declaring a Variable with Apex for a TriggerHandler

Tags: apex

I am working on a TriggerHandler and I am pretty new to Apex. Below is my code. I am trying to declare a variable 'cl' for an object createCreditNoteLine and to use a map. Can anyone take a look at the blow and assist me with declaring the variable.

Apex //Map of String and Credit Note Line

```
    Map<String, blng__CreditNoteLine__c> myMap = new Map<String, blng__CreditNoteLine__c>();                                                            
    for(blng__CreditNoteLine__c : cl) {
            if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
                System.debug('creating new Credit Note Line');
                createCreditNoteLine(cl);
            } else {
                System.debug('Updating existing Credit Note Line');
                updateCreditNoteLine(cl);
            }
        }
    }
if(creditNoteLinesToUpsert.size() > 0) {
        System.debug('creditNoteLinesToUpsert: ' + creditNoteLinesToUpsert);
        upsert creditNoteLinesToUpsert;
```

Comment: What is the cl variable supposed to hold?

Comment: is this a separate class/method and if so, are you passing Trigger.new to it and if yes, into what variable?

Comment: It is a triggerhandler class that extends a trigger class. The variable should be for a single credit note line.

Comment: please use [edit] to show the trigger calling the method and the method definition in the trigger handler

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are iterating the map values. You have to put a name for the for left statement:

```
for(blng__CreditNoteLine__c cl : myMap.values()) {
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
            System.debug('creating new Credit Note Line');
            createCreditNoteLine(cl);
        } else {
            System.debug('Updating existing Credit Note Line');
            updateCreditNoteLine(cl);
        }
    }
}
```